# How many times can I create Client instance in one session?

Tags: javascript, braintree

I'm building a one page web app, trying to setup payments with Braintree. I get this exception any time I try to teardown  for a second time:

```
r {name: "BraintreeError", code: "METHOD_CALLED_AFTER_TEARDOWN", message: "teardown cannot be called after teardown.", type: "MERCHANT", details: undefined}
```

The problem is that I call this on a completely different instance of HostedFields, created for different Client...

Is this a bug or maybe I shouldn't call **braintree.client.create** twice?

Thanks!

Comment: Please contact Braintree support. Would be great if you could include a reproducible example.

Comment: Meant to include the link: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact